# Cakephp warning session_start(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, cakephp

When I try to load any page it gives me a warning:

> session_start(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

This warning arises in random fashion.

### Debug Log:

#### Code

```
// For IE<=8
session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate");
session_start();
```

#### Context

```
session_start - [internal], line ??
CakeSession::_startSession() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 618
CakeSession::start() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 190
CakeSession::read() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 366
SessionComponent::read() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php, line 71
ToolbarComponent::__construct() - APP/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php, line 164
ComponentCollection::load() - CORE/Cake/Controller/ComponentCollection.php, line 116
ComponentCollection::init() - CORE/Cake/Controller/ComponentCollection.php, line 53
Controller::constructClasses() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 643
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 183
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 110
```

Comment: looks not related to cakephp .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat

Comment: I figured this issue, this is due to load balancing of server. thanks for help.