# Php error on homepage only (DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses)

Tags: php, dom, amazon-web-services, dns, warnings

I am getting the following php error on my homepage

```
DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known.
```

This is odd because I actually cannot find a lot of information on this error anywhere. The only info I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat)
In which he basically claims it is a temporary error, mine has been like this for over 24 hours so I figured I would ask for some help. If i simply change the url the whole site works, database, all functionality this error is only on the homepage.

This happens when I take an image of my aws micro instance, and clone it to a large instance. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the entire code of your script please?

Comment: its just html in a php file, I am not running any script, just html on the homepage.