# Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0) (Acquia Connector login for drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, authentication, migrate, acquia

I've been having this error when logging in my subscription in Acquia Cloud:

> Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0)

I think it is a PHP problem, not sure. I dont know how to troubleshoot it.

I want to migrate my local drupal site in the Acquia Cloud for my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you were logging in from a saved url then seems like your url has expired. Please try again directly from the acquia website with a fresh url.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when trying to run composer commands on CentOS virtual machine. The solution that worked came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat) post.
In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, set `ServerName` to 127.0.0.1:80. Restart apache service.