# php error when submitting comment

Tags: php

I have an error in the php code for submitting a comment, the problem is the 4th line of code:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: the requested name is
>   valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Any ideas?

```
    <?php
if( $_POST )
{
  $con = mysql_connect('%', 'myuser', 'mypassword');

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("_mysite", $link);

  $users_name = $_POST['name'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_website = $_POST['website'];
  $users_comment = $_POST['comment'];

  $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($users_name);
  $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
  $users_website = mysql_real_escape_string($users_website);
  $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);

  $articleid = $_GET['id'];
  if( ! is_numeric($articleid) )
    die('invalid article id');

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `_mysite`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`,
        `comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_name',
        '$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid');";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: What's unclear about the error message in specific?

Comment: This is the first time i have ever seen `%` host. `mysql_connect('%'`

Answer (score 0):

The `%` is mysql's wildcard, when you use it for your user's allowed host, it means ['any host'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html), in your case here it should probably be localhost.

Not related to your question, but if you're not aware of it you should consider moving away from `mysql_` functions which are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), mysqli is the recommended replacement.

Comment: You have a typo in "mysqli is the recommended replacement" you probably meant to type PDO

Comment: meant the direct replacement as it is almost plug and play. I do prefer PDO though don't worry

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$link` with `$con` in this line `mysql_select_db("_mysite", $link);`. 
This is the first time i am seeing any server name as `%`. I don't have much idea about it. But, you can replace `%` with `localhost` or `port number` or `IP Address`

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword');

  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("_mysite", $con);

  $users_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $users_website = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['website']);
  $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

  $articleid = $_GET['id'];

  if(!is_numeric($articleid))
    die('invalid article id');

  $query = "INSERT INTO `_mysite`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`,`comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$users_name','$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid')";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Please stop using `mysql*` functions. These extensions have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about prepared statements for `PDO` and `MySQLi`.

**Using MySqli**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword", "_mysite");
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $users_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
  $users_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
  $users_website = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['website']);
  $users_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comment']);

  $articleid = $_GET['id'];

  if(!is_numeric($articleid))
    die('invalid article id');

  $query = "INSERT INTO `_mysite`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `website`,`comment`, `timestamp`, `articleid`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '$users_name','$users_email', '$users_website', '$users_comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid')";

  mysqli_query($con,$query)

  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Refer [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat) for more details.