# Connection could not be established with host eoptronic.com :stream_socket_client():

Tags: php, laravel, email

i get below error when trying to create *RESET PASSWORD* feature.

[image]

this is my **.env** :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=eoptronic.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=supp.idn@eoptronic.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="******"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=supp.idn@eoptronic.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

i also did adding this code in **config/mail.php** :

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'supp.idn@eoptronic.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'EOI Developer - Reset Password'),
],
```

Comment: Seems like your DNS server couldn't resolve the hostname.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP error: php\_network\_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: (while getting information from other site.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275535/php-error-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-while-getting-informat)

Comment: sorry for late reply. but it helped and solved my problem. thanks mate @ADyson and @.liamfiddler

Answer (score 0):

try with MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls and MAIL_PORT=587
After above changes also clear laravel cache with following

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

This may be issue within your local network or ISP check if you could resolve mx records for your domain.